# Is there a way to view/log a javascript function in object format?

Tags: javascript, function, object, console.log

We're just learning that functions are objects in javascript. I'm trying to visualise it but can't manage it with console.log() - for example I have tried:

```js
function exampleFunc() {
  console.log("foo")
};

console.log(exampleFunc.toString()) // returns function exampleFunc(){console.log("foo")}

console.log(JSON.stringify(exampleFunc)) //returns undefined
```

Neither of these methods log what I recognise as object notation. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I get an error from the first one because you shouldn't be calling the function if you want to get the string of the function itself.

Comment: If you want to view the function as an object, why are you converting it to a string?

Comment: The second one is clearly a typo, the OP meant to write `exampleFunc.toString()` and should probably edit it. And of course, true, there was no need to call `toString()` inside a `console.log` call, but I think the OP was just trying lots of things by way of example....

Comment: Thanks @RayToal I've edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `console.dir` to be able to examine the function as an object:

```js
function foo() {
}

console.dir(foo);
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```js
function exampleFunc(){console.log("foo")};
console.log(exampleFunc.name); // will return you: exampleFunc
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.